# Why does view.safeAreaInsets.top contain bad value in viewDidLayoutSubviews()?

Tags: swift, autolayout, insets, safearea

Running iOS 16.1 app through XCode iPhone 14 Pro Max (phy. device), where 'view' is my VC's main view, I'm getting a `view.safeAreaInset.top` value of 97.66666... which is much higher than the 59.0 value for the safearea than everything online says it should be for that device model.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print(view.safeLayoutInsets.top)
}
```

However, views I constrain to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor` in my AutoLayout constraints don't appear to be in the wrong place on the screen visually...  So it's almost as if the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` and `safeAreaInsets` are disagreeing for the same view.

Any idea why it's off, and more importantly the proper way to extract the correct value in the code?

Interestingly if I add this viewDidLayoutSubviews() I do get the correct 59.0 value...

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.map({ $0 as? UIWindowScene }).compactMap({ $0 }).first?.windows.first {
    print(window.safeAreaInsets.top)
}
```

Comment: Are you in a Navigation Controller ?

Comment: @DonMag Yes ... Hmmmm.... I mean, not me personally ;-)

Comment: *grin* ...  the `.safeAreaInsets` accounts for the navigation bar height. So, yes, `97.666...` is correct.